# excel cells that display content based on cells "position" in a column

Tags: excel

I'm trying to change the value of cells based on the relative position (rows) of cells in a particular column. 
To illustrate:

```
Name    Up   Down   NoMove   New
Bob     0    0      1        0     
Fred    0    0      1        0 
Jane    0    0      1        0 
Peter   0    0      1        0 
etc
```

External sources will change the position of the people (Bob, Fred). When that happens the 4 columns should reflect the current state relative to the previous state

```
Name    Up   Down   NoMove   New
Fred    1    0      0        0     
Bob     0    1      0        0 
Jane    0    0      1        0 
Alan    1    0      0        1 
etc
```

I've looked all over Stackoverflow but can't find anything that might work. I'm not even sure if it's possible but maybe I don't have the terminology correct. Can someone tell me where to look or provide a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: No very clear what you are trying to do. 1) Do you expect that to happen in the same sheet? *(i.e. before and after tables are the same sheet, the second view is same table altered by what you called `external sources`)*.  It's seems not possible. You need a copy of the original table to compare. If the original view is gone then there is nothing to compare to.

Comment: You need to describe your problem more clearly. In VBA you could maybe  write an event handler for the `Worksheet_Change` event -- which according to this ( https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/919a7ca5-85a8-476b-a66c-0924eee80743/will-a-vba-worksheet-change-event-be-triggered-by-a-dde-external-link?forum=isvvba ) is triggered by a change in the data from a DDE external link.

Comment: Apologies if it's not very clear. Just to clarify: The positions of the names in the Name column are updated externally (they will just be referenced from another section of the same sheet). Ideally there is only one table on the same sheet. Calculations could be done on another sheet, however.  Maybe a 'snapshot' of the sheet is taken before updating and then the new sheet is compared to the snapshot? Not sure if that's feasible. The steps are quite straightforward: change in Name position affects other columns, but I guess the implementation is hard.

Comment: Could you help us understand to what end is this needed?  Is this the final output desired or are you going to do something with this table?  If this is not the final desired output there may be an easier method to get the final desired output.  As to What to do.  I would load all the names and positions into an array or dictionary during the load and then compare the load position to the array or dictionary.  But again it depends on the final outcome desired.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for asking. Actually the values here will end up in a MySQL database. I have a table inside the DB with the Name, up, down, etc fields. Essentially my excel spreadsheet contains a plains list of names. The order of the names will change on a regular basis (and will have new entries). So even better would be to figure out a way of manipulating the data in SQL and updating the table directly from the plain list. But I was trying to do it in the spreadsheet first. Any recommendations welcome. Maybe the list goes to an array which can then be manipulated on each change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a piece of code like this:-

```
Sub UpDown()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim var As Variant
Dim name As String
Dim Position As Long

With ActiveSheet

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

    Range("B:B").Cells(i) = 0
    Range("C:C").Cells(i) = 0
    Range("D:D").Cells(i) = 0
    Range("E:E").Cells(i) = 0

    var = Application.Match(Range("A:A").Cells(i), Range("F:F"), 0)
' Not found
    If (IsError(var)) Then
       Range("E:E").Cells(i) = 1
' Found
    Else
        Position = var
    ' Moved up
        If i < Position Then
            Range("B:B").Cells(i) = 1
        Else
    ' Stayed the same
            If i = Position Then
                Range("D:D").Cells(i) = 1
            Else
        ' Moved down
                Range("C:C").Cells(i) = 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
 Next i

'Copy names

For i = 2 To LastRow
    Range("F:F").Cells(i) = Range("A:A").Cells(i)
Next i

End With

End Sub
```

I assigned it to a button in order to test it, but you could also make it a change event handler so that it ran every time something in column A changed, or run it on a timer as described [here](http://excelexperts.com/VBA-Tips-Run-Code-Every-Hour-Minute-or-Second).

Starting conditions:-

[image]

First pass:-

[image]

Second pass:-

[image]

Comment: Position should have been declared as Long, not Integer, have corrected this.